# Docker service names interaction between containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Just some questions from a newbie docker user.

I am using three `docker-compose.yml` files. One for three nginx services, one for the first web app and database, the last one for the second web app and database. The docker containers with each container and purpose as below.

1. nginx gen
2. nginx letsencrypt
3. nginx
4. web server 1
5. database 1 (for web server 1 only)
6. web server 2
7. database 2 (for web server 2 only)

Now on to the questions.

1. In my second and third `docker-compose.yml` files I used the same service name and I have experienced an issue in the application. Web server 1 sometimes see database 1 but sometimes switches to database 2. It is because I am using the service name as configuration for database host in app configuration. Is the service name in `docker-compose.yml` should be unique?
2. Can we name docker service as we like? Is there a naming convention to this?
3. What is the best practice for setting host configuration for apps inside docker? Should we use its container IP? Or should we use the service name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, if they're in the same network.
2. Do as you like
3. IP is definitely not done. Docker was made partly to run your app distributed on multiple machines, if you use a container orchestration tool like kubernetes, the IP might change constantly. referring to a host by its servicename is somewhat ok (as long as they're in the same network), but ideally you would spin up a container for service discovery (Eureka, Zuul, Consul,...) and let each service register itself as a service there. Your 1st question already addresses a problem that you could face with referring to a service by its servicename.